# MJML: mj-include fails to read file

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-email, markup, mjml

Firstly, I am new at emails markup. So I decided to use mjml to construct a letter but I faced the problem - markup doesn't being rendered properly:
MJML doesn't include components and I can't understand why. Project was created using npm package mjml-component-boilerplate because I wanted to register my own components.

my index.mjml

```
<mj-body>
    <mj-include path="./components/blocks/header.mjml" />
    <mj-include path="./components/blocks/main.mjml" />
    <mj-include path="./components/blocks/footer.mjml" />
  </mj-body>
```

part of output index.html (the same with main.mjml and footer.mjml)

```
<div>
        <!-- mj-include fails to read file : ./components/blocks/header.mjml at D:\projects\ctc_projects\chetv\site\reshala_promo\email\components\blocks\header.mjml -->
```

header.mjml

```
<mj-section>
    <mj-column>
        <mj-div css-class="header">
            <mj-image
                    src="/assets/images/logo.png"
                    alt="ЧЕ!"
                    title="https://chetv.ru/"
                    href="https://chetv.ru/"
                    target="__blank"
                    css-class="header__logo"
            />
        </mj-div>
    </mj-column>
</mj-section>
```

and, for a case, if it will make any sense my MjDiv component

```
import { registerDependencies } from 'mjml-validator'
import { BodyComponent } from 'mjml-core'

registerDependencies({
    'mj-body': ['mj-div'],
    'mj-column': ['mj-div'],
    'mj-section': ['mj-div'],

    'mj-div': [
        'mj-text', 'mj-image', 'mj-accordion',
        'mj-carousel', 'mj-divider', 'mj-group',
        'mj-navbar', 'mj-raw', 'mj-social',
        'mj-div', 'mj-a', 'mj-p', 'mj-h1'
    ]
});

export default class MjDivComponent extends BodyComponent {
  static endingTag = true;

  static allowedAttributes = {
      'css-class': 'css-class',
      'style': 'style'
  };

  render() {
    return `<div
        ${this.htmlAttributes({
          class: this.getAttribute('css-class'),
          style: this.getAttribute('style')
        })}
      >${this.getContent()}</div>`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You demonstrate putting the `<mj-include>` components after `<mj-body>` (as demonstrated in https://mjml.io/documentation/#mj-include). It *doesn't work* for me there.

It *does work* for me when I put the `<mj-include>` elements after `<mj-head>`. Good luck!

I'm interpreting the rest of your post as background, not asking another question. Let me know if otherwise.

By the way: Besides stackoverflow, another great source of MJML information is https://mjml.slack.com.

Comment: well, actually, finally I decided not to use this MLML but yeah your answer was useful

Answer (score -1):

```
    <mj-section padding="0px">
        <mj-column>
            <mj-text align="center" padding="0px">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
```

Comment: Please consider an explaination to your source-code-only answer